# appending div in javascript with dynamic id

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am appending div to my html in javascript.
But I want it id to be dynamic.

```
for(var i=0;i<$scope.step.about.OrganizeAnswer.length;i++){
   $('#dropArea').append('<div  id="drop_0">Beginning</div>');
}
```

I want id as drop_0,drop_1... according to for loop

Comment: `$('#dropArea').append('<div  id="drop_'+i+' ">Beginning</div>');`

Comment: people who answer should upvote the question

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to manipulate your DOM in loop.

Use string to concate in the loop, once loop finish append it.

```
var div = "";
for(var i=0;i<$scope.step.about.OrganizeAnswer.length;i++){
   div += '<div  id="drop_'+i+'">Beginning</div>';
}
$('#dropArea').append(div);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace 0 with i as below:

```
for (var i=0;i<$scope.step.about.OrganizeAnswer.length;i++){
       $('#dropArea').append('<div  id="drop_'+i+'">Beginning</div>');
}
```